# How do compilers implement __declspec(align(x)) / __attribute__((aligned(x)))?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, alignment, memory-alignment

Imagine a structure like this:

```
struct S {
    __declspec(align(32)) double A[4]; // MSVC / ICL on Windows
    double A[4] __attribute__((aligned(x))); // CLANG / GCC
};
```

The structure can be allocated on stack or using malloc for instance, either way the structure instance itself may not be aligned. So can we count on the member A being 32-byte aligned? If so how does the compiler do that?

Comment: Look for `alignas`.

Comment: Thanks and that one would work? Can you please elaborate how then? I mean I assume the compiler can allocate "worst case scenario" and then just align the pointer when used, but then you'd have a problem if you'd memcpy the structure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least for MSVC as the docs for __declspec(align()) say it only affects static and automatic object allocations, not dynamic allocations. If you want to control dynamic allocation alignment you will need to use a function such as _aligned_malloc that provides that ability.

Comment: You get warning `C4316` when using one of these types with `new`.